# Split a [Char] by each character in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, split, character

I'm new to Haskell and I would like some help into how to split a sentence into separate characters.

Example: `"Test sentence" == ["T","e","s","t"," ","s","e","n","t","e","n","c","e"]`

I checked everywhere but cant find a solution that don't require import of separate modules and stuff.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `"Test sentence"` is the *exact* same value as `['T','e','s','t',' ','s','e','n','t','e','n','c','e']`, just using a different literal syntax. Try entering both at a ghci prompt.

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell a `String` is a type synonym for `[Char]`.

If you really want to turn a `[Char]` into a lists of one-character `String`s (you probably don't):

```hs
charStrs :: String -> [String]
charStrs = fmap pure

charStrs "hello world" -- ["h","e","l","l","o"," ","w","o","r","l","d"]
```

*edit* updated to `pure`

Comment: As long as you have the type signature, you can even define `charStrs = fmap pure`.

Comment: Its exactly that I want. Thanks.